# Is the restriction of a simple sheaf of modules simple?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, sheaf-theory

Let $X$ be a topological space, $A$ a sheaf of (unital and associative but not necessarily commutative) rings on $X$. Suppose $M$ is a simple quasicoherent $A$-module and $U$ an open subset of $X$. Is $M|_U$ a simple $A|_U$-module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Restriction is an exact functor split by its right adjoint (pushforward).  If $M|_{U}$ has a proper non-zero quotient $N$, then $i_*N$ receives a non-zero and thus injective map from $M$.  However, this means that $M|_U$ must map injectively to $N$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by split? I haven't seen that term in this context before.

Comment: In this case, I mean its right adjoint is a 1-sided inverse.